# Why is this definition of Natural Numbers correct in Maude?

Tags: maude-system

Why is the following a correct implementation of natural numbers?

```
mod PEANO-NAT is
  sort Nat .
  op zero : -> Nat .
  op succ : Nat -> Nat .
  op plus : Nat Nat -> Nat .
  vars N M : Nat .
  eq plus(zero, M) = M .
  eq plus(succ(N), M) = succ(plus(N, M)) .
endm
```

in particular I am having a hard time understanding the last two lines nad how they make sure natural numbers are defined correctly. Any help

Answer (score 1):

A better question could be: Why is this definition of the *Addition* in the Natural Numbers correct?

To answer that question, we must prove that with those two equations, the Addition is a Commutative Monoid. That means: `a + b = b + a`.

You can try to do that using induction, for the base case and for the inductive step.

Give it a try. I am happy to help.